# Angular Google Charts - Unable to change Pie Slice Colors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I am unable to change the Pie Chart colors. Currently it is only the default colors. 
[image: PieChart]

How do I define the colors? Below is my current chartObject. It works just fine when I change to BarChart or ColumnChart ie bar colors change. Just not for the PieChart. What I am doing wrong?

```
chartObject = {"type":"PieChart",
"data":{"cols":[{"id":"label","label":"Action Status","type":"string"},
{"id":"label","label":"Number of Actions","type":"number"},
{"role":"style","type":"string","p":{"role":"style"}}],
"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Open"},{"v":2},{"v":"ORANGE"}]},
{"c":[{"v":"Close"},{"v":1},{"v":"GREEN"}]}]},
"options":{"title":"Legal Register Tracking"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **slices** in options data object and give color json object `'slices': [{color:'yellow'},{color:'red'}]` for each slices

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart']);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) 
{
    $scope.chartObject = {};

    $scope.chartObject.type = "PieChart";

    $scope.chartObject.data = {"cols": 
    [
        {id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string"},
        {id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number"}
    ], 

    "rows": 
    [
        {c: 
            [
                {v: "Mushrooms"},
                {v: 3},
                {color: 'black'}
            ]
        },

        {c: 
            [
                {v: "Pepperoni"},
                {v: 2},
            ]
        }
    ]};

    $scope.chartObject.options = {
        'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
        'slices': [{color:'yellow'},{color:'red'}]
    };
});
```

Comment: you can also use `'colors': ['red', 'yellow', 'cyan']`  -- [Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options)

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks nice one